# AppFabric vs. NCache - A Detailed Feature Comparison

Tags: appfabric, ncache

I need to compare and contrast AppFabric with NCache.  Which is better in large-scale programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comparison](http://www.alachisoft.com/comparison/appfabric-vs-ncache.html) is between AppFabric v1.1 and NCache 4.3 SP1. It describes major feature differences between both products.

Comment: Note that that link is to NCache's own web site.

Comment: @stuartd Exactly. They are drawing a colored picture there. It would make more sense to add AppFabric to [this comparison](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/edition-comparison.html). By the way, they are stating AppFabric does not support Data Encryption. When I look into the [AppFabric Security Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718179%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), I think it is not correct, is it?